# Scala pattern matching on List containing Options not receiving type?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Trying to fix a client API but running into a problem here:

```
case Some(List(Some(msgType:String), Some(channel:String), Some(data:String))) =>
        List(Some(msgType:String), Some(channel:String), Some(data:String)).foreach {
            msgType match {
              case "message" | "pmessage" => 
                fn(M(channel, data))
              case x => throw new RuntimeException("unhandled message: " + x)
            }
        }
```

When I go to compile the code, I get the error `type mismatch; found : Any required: Some[String] => ?` at `fn(M(channel, data))`

How do I properly structure the matching so it receives type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break this up a bit:

```
case Some(List(Some(msgType:String), Some(channel:String), Some(data:String))) =>
    List(Some(msgType:String), Some(channel:String), Some(data:String)).foreach {
```

So, at this point, you have to provide a function from `Option[String]` to something. That's the crucial point: you need to pass a function as parameter to `foreach`. Let's proceed:

```
        msgType match {
```

You might be laboring under the impression that this is a function -- it is not. Maybe you understand that, but, just in case, let me explain this point. A function takes an argument and returns something else: it can be declared in a number of ways:

```
x => f(x) // anonymous function
{ case x => f(x) } // pattern-matching anonymous function
f _ // eta expansion of method f
f(_) // partial function application
_ + 1 // anonymous function with placeholder syntax
```

Note that `msgType match {` is none of the above.

Now, `msgType` here refers to what was matched in the first case. It will exactly the same for each invocation of `foreach` (which will iterator through `msgType`, `channel` and `data`, and, therefore, call the passed function three times).

```
          case "message" | "pmessage" => 
            fn(M(channel, data))
```

And now we arrive at the point of the problem. `fn(M(channel,data))` is the function that will be passed to `foreach`, so the return type of `fn` must be `String => ???`. Since you didn't provide any information about `fn` or `M`, we have no way of assessing what might be the problem.

However, maybe you did not intend for `fn` to return a function, and messed up on the `foreach`. Again, you did not explain what you wanted to accomplish, so I can't explain how to accomplish it.

```
          case x => throw new RuntimeException("unhandled message: " + x)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Much more detailed and certainly explains where I went wrong. You're correct, I didn't write the foreach properly. My apologies for not fully explaining my intended result. Essentially, the intention was to loop through each message and create a fn(M()) which are defined classes in scope. They answer to a callback in an Akka actor :)

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
myList match {
  case Some(xs @ List(Some(msgType:String), Some(channel:String), Some(data:String))) =>
    xs.foreach {...}
  case _ => {...}
}
```

I hope it helps, even if a cleaner way certainly exists.

Comment: The only problem with the above is that the incoming pattern isn't always a list. I'd agree, it looks like it works but sometimes it is also a sequence, so I'm not always matching a list. I did get it working and it turns out I was rewriting the foreach improperly. I'll post an answer in a sec...

Comment: Instead of `Some(List(...)) => list.get` you can type `Some(xs @ List(...)) => xs`

Comment: Thanks, that's the better way I was thinking about.